# What's the difference between Rpi kernel source and Rpi distro kernels?

Tags: kernel, driver, modules

I need a specific kernel module (driver for a USB grabber), which is included in kernel 3.12. So, I went for Pidora, which features kernel 3.12 but was surprised, that the module wasn't included in the distro kernel.

So what's the difference between the Pidora kernel source (or any other Rpi distro) and the Rpi kernel source (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.12.y).

Comment: which module? Fedora kernels can often have extra modules added (they are missed out as they are not fully open-source/finished), but these are probably not available for the Pi's version - if it is a Fedora kernel not a RPi one..

Comment: It's about this one: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.12.y/drivers/media/usb/usbtv What's the preferred way to include this module?